# Update if not exists in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to run an `update` statement in SQL Server that skips rows that already exist in the target?

For instance, I have a view `vw_BranchCaseCurrent` which contains a `CaseID` and a `BranchID`, in addition to an auto-incremented `ID`. I want to do this:

```
update a
set
    a.CaseID = @NewCaseID
from vw_BranchCaseCurrent a
where
    a.CaseID = @OldCaseID;
```

But the problem is, if there is already an existing row in `vw_BranchCaseCurrent` for the *new* `CaseID` and the existing `BranchID` then this SQL will crash because it is violating the unique constraint on the backing table. So I'd need to skip that row when performing the `update`.

I was thinking maybe I could use a `merge` statement but I'm not entirely familiar with how those work...

There are about a dozen other views that need to be updated so I'm looking for something simple, if possible...

edit: let me clarify with an example:

```
| CaseID | BranchID |
|--------|----------|
| 42     | 8008     |
| 42     | 9001     |
| 86     | 9001     |
```

So I want to merge case 42 into case 86 by updating the `CaseID` field in this view. I want to change the first `CaseID` from 42 to 86. But the second row, I can't do anything with this because the `BranchID` of 9001 already exists for `CaseID` 86. So I leave that one alone.

This is a simple example; some of the other views I need to merge have multiple ID fields in addition to the `CaseID`...

Comment: `WHERE ... AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a WHERE CaseID = @NewCaseId)`? I mean, you practically put it in the title yourself...

Comment: Well, it's not the case ID itself that needs to be unique, it's the combination of case ID and the other columns, which are different depending on which view is being updated! But yeah, thanks :)

Comment: If you need to do a lot of column comparisons, one quick trick slash hack is to use the fact that the `EXCEPT` operator (`SELECT x EXCEPT SELECT y`) compares `NULL` values "in the expected way", which saves a lot of `AND (a.x = b.x OR (a.x IS NULL AND b.x IS NULL))` boilerplate. Combine this with CTEs for your input tables (`WITH x AS (...) UPDATE`) and you can get some pretty concise code. `MERGE` looks superficially attractive, but has clunky syntax and has a bad rep because of past bugs in the implementation (which are hopefully all ironed out by now, but still).

Comment: Hmm. Not sure how this is going to work. So let's say I have two cases with IDs 42 and 86, and I also have two branches with IDs 8008 and 9001. 8008 is associated with both cases, while 9001 is associated only with case 42 I want to migrate the data from case 42 to case 86. So branch 9001 will be migrated just fine. but branch 8008 will throw an error because there is already a row with case 86 and branch 8008. This is the scenario I'm trying to avoid; in this scenario I want to skip changing the `CaseID` on that record in `vw_BranchCaseCurrent`.

Comment: If I simply set a `where` clause to skip rows where the new `CaseID` already exists in the view, won't that skip too many rows?

Comment: OK, I think a modified version of @JeroenMostert's where clause might work: `and not exists (select * from vw_BranchCaseCurrent b where b.BranchID = a.BranchID and b.CaseID = @NewCaseID)`

Answer (score 0):

You can express this using `not exists`, `not in`, or a `left join` . . . or even using window functions.

```
with toupdate as (
       select bcc.*, sum(case when CaseID = @NewCaseID then 1 else 0 end) over () as num_new
       from vw_BranchCaseCurrent bcc
      )
update toupdate
    set CaseID = @NewCaseID
    where CaseID = @OldCaseID and num_new = 0;
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure how that will work - won't the `sum` be 1 only for rows that have the `@NewCaseID`? But we want to skip updating rows that have the `@OldCaseID` if all the other IDs in the rows matches in the row with the `@NewCaseID`.

Comment: @ekolis I'm pretty sure in Gordon's query the order of operations is to check the Value as True/False [0 or 1]. So it would be ignored by the Update. But, since The Value has not been set yet. Remember WHERE clauses are second in execution. It's not setting it to 1 like you think.

Comment: @ekolis . . . Not exactly.  As originally formulated, it would have been a syntax error.  Now that I've added the window function part, it counts the number of `@NewCaseID` already in the data.